# wpf converter in xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, valueconverter

I know there are a few ways to use value converter in xaml, like using StaticResource to get converter from resources or Static to get from a static instance. My question is, for whatever reason, I have a converter instance created in the code behind, and can be accessed through a non static property, How can I use this instance of converter in xaml for binding?

Thanks,

Q

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the converter as part of a binding, you could create the binding in your code behind also, and hook it up to the control you want to in code.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that, but trying to see if there is one way to use the converter in xaml for binding.